# Will change distro speed up boot up time?

Tags: linux, boot, lightweight

I have an old-ish laptop with a Celeron cpu. 3 Gb of RAM. I had manjaro lxqt installed, but because I rarely use it anymore, a rolling distro isn't very appropriate. Every time I wanted to update it, it wanted 1.5 Gb of updates.

My current internet connection is stable, but not much bandwidth.

Therefore I installed PopOS!, because I had that handy on a stick. Then installed LXQT with it for a lightweight distro. It works well. I also installed `lightdm`.

I might be wrong, but it seems boot time is a bit longer than it was with manjaro.

Would changing distro improve boot time? Like Lubuntu? I have the intuition that the base system won't be much faster and the biggest gains are on the desktop - but I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe kernel version should have more impact on boot time than distro in itself. However, there are other factors that might come into play. For instance on Ubuntu:

- Having "snapd" (snapcraft) enabled can increase boottime

There might be other similar daemons/packages/technologies in different distros that on themselves add to boot time.

Comment: No snapd. But good comments, thanks.